# How to Configure Access Point Policy for Listing Objects Within a Folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to do exactly what this article shows:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-folder-user-access/

But with an access point policy that allows users from another AWS account to access a specific folder within my AWS account s3 bucket and

1. List all objects within the folder of the bucket
2. Get an object from within the folder of the bucket

I have configured #2 but cannot figure out how to configure #1. Here is my policy so far.
Can anyone help?

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowListObjectOperationsInS3Prefix",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::YYY:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:us-east-1:XXX:accesspoint/ap",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": "something/*"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowGetObjectOperationsInS3Prefix",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::YYY:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:us-east-1:XXX:accesspoint/ap/object/something/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It seems that you are tying to give access to the bucket in account 1 to the user in account 2. This is a two-steps process. First you need to attach an IAM policy to the user, which explicitly allows him to access the bucket. Second, you need to create a resource-based policy in the account with your bucket. This policy should grant access to that user's principal. Did you do both of these steps?

Comment: I am going the access point route so I configured the bucket policy to allow users of account YYY to access the bucket. Also, I am giving access to all users of account YYY which is why I didn't configure an IAM policy on the user, and instead just gave access at the root level for the access point policy. Using this method, I am able to download content as a user of YYY and I can see ALL objects in account XXX's bucket (when i take out the Condition key in AllowListObjectOperationsInS3Prefix), but i want to limit this to only seeing objects in one folder.

Comment: Hope that answers your question and gives insight into where I'm stuck.

Comment: OK, I see. I think the prob is how you define the prefix in the policy. It should be `ap/something/*`. Also the principal from YYY account  who has the access is only your root user and not IAM users...

Comment: I tried that but with no luck :( Also thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @SahifaShadih Can you check and let me know if the answer I provided is working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution. You may want to limit the allowed actions to best suit your use case.

For this you will need a bucket (`test-bucket`) in `AccountA` and an access point (`test-ap)` in the same account. In another account `AccountB`, you will need an IAM user (or you can choose to set up an IAM role), which we will call `UserInAccountB`.

We need three policies to achieve our goal. First, we need an IAM policy in the AccountB. It should look similar to the policy below and it should be attached to the `UserInAccountB`.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:us-east-1:AccountA:accesspoint/",
                "arn:aws:s3:us-east-1:AccountA:accesspoint/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Further, we need two policies in the AccountA: One S3 policy and one Access Point policy. S3 policy should be attached to the S3 bucket `test-bucket` and it should  look something like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAccessToIamUser",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountB:user/UserInAccountB"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Finally, we need the following policy attached to the access point `test-ap`:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAccessToIamUser",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::user/UserInAccountB"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:us-east-1:AccountA:accesspoint/test-ap",
                "arn:aws:s3:us-east-1:AccountA:accesspoint/test-ap/object/public*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": "public/*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Notice that the two policies are similar, but not the same.

To test that our solution is working correctly, we can create two folders `public` and `private` and add an object `testObject` to both of them.

When we run the following command:
`aws s3 ls  s3://arn:aws:s3:us-east-1:AccountA:accesspoint/test-ap/public/ --profile AccountB-Profile` we will see our `testObject` listed. If we run the same command against our private folder (`aws s3 ls  s3://arn:aws:s3:us-east-1:AccountA:accesspoint/test-ap/private/ --profile AccountB-Profile`) we will get an `Access Denied`.

Finally, to download our `testObject` locally, we can run: `aws s3 cp  s3://arn:aws:s3:us-east-1:AccountA:accesspoint/test-ap/public/testObject . --profile AccountB-Profile`